# How has academic research on Massive Open Online Courses (MOOCs) improved MOOCs?

Tags: teaching, mooc

It seems that the number of more academic papers on Massive Open Online Courses (MOOCs) surpasses the number of MOOCs. Is there any indication that academic research on MOOCs has actually improved MOOCs? And if so, in what way?

Comment: I like this question a lot, but it seems a bit broad for a SE website.  You could probably write a research paper (or at least a lit review) on this topic.

Comment: Interesting although very vague. What does 'improving' mean in this context? Also, the assumption? There are more published research papers on MOOCs than there are MOOCs actually available to study with? Not quite sure. Then if educational research improved education, the world would be very different, or maybe it does already.